# Photos optimize and cache

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, optimization, photo

I'm working on a community website for travellers. After a lot of usertesting, it seems that "uploading photos" is the main aspect that users like. Just 3 testusers provide more than 4000 photos in 5 months time. My question is: what if I have 1000 users, how will I (or my server) be able to manage this correctly? I'm doubting to step out of beta and opening it for everybody before having a solid solution for this potential problem.

- I'm working with PHP (mainly CodeIgniter)
- Images are uploaded and cropped in 3 sizes (I save them all on the server)
- I use Cloudfare to get some performance support

**How can I optimize this aspect to avoid serverproblems etc.?**

- Shouldn't I save the images, but render them with PHP?
- What is the best way to cache them?
- Should I use external-services to upload/save/maintain these photos?
- ...

It's a general question, but really important for me.
I highly appreciate all the tips and know-how of you people!

Thanks in advance!
G

Answer (score 0):

My tips:

- resize them directly after uploading in the desired resolutions, as you do now; rendering them on-the-fly all the time eats up a lot of CPU.
- cache: store them as regular files in your webdirectory, say in /images; your webserver can then serve them directly. Create a 2-level subdirectory structure to prevent a huge number of files in one directory. I suggestion taking the MD5 hash from the original file, then use the first 2x2 bytes as subdirectories, the rest as filename.

E.g. the md5sum of the file is `4ad5ec63e6c771a4f1c91e4d19bdf921` and you want to render 3 resolutions (small, medium, large). The (resized) files on disk are then named:

```
/images/4a/d5/ec63e6c771a4f1c91e4d19bdf921_s.jpg
/images/4a/d5/ec63e6c771a4f1c91e4d19bdf921_m.jpg
/images/4a/d5/ec63e6c771a4f1c91e4d19bdf921_l.jpg
```

Store the hash in your database.

If the traffic from images grows significantly, you may consider using a separate server that just serves images (e.g. from http://images.domain.com/), off-loading your PHP server.

Comment: Thank you very much! Currently I'm uploading the files, resize them directly into /uploads, /uploads/thumb, /uploads/medium, /uploads/large, such this aspect is covered I guess. If I store these names in the database (which I now do, linking it to a traveller), how is this exactly handling the cache?

Comment: Actually, caching is done by the browser. When it requests an image for the second time it sends a "Modified-Since" header or something like that with a timestamp from the previous fetch. If the file hasn't changed on disk the browser returns a 304 "Not modified" HTTP status code. But the webserver still has to check on disk for the timestamp on the file. If you want to prevent this you can force Apache to send extra Expire headers that will tell the browser not to check for changes unless the user forces it. Of course, you have to be quite sure the images don't change.